# simulation of correlated data with specifications on covariance matrix

Tags: r, covariance

Hi I would like to generate correlated binary data (0/1) for 60 variables at a time.
I tried some packages like `bindata`, and `mvrnorm` but I mostly get an error telling me that the random correlation matrix I give is not right. (i tried to create it from a truncated normal distribution...)

The only thing I want is to specify the average correlation between my variables, like 0.7, and have some negative correlations too. Is that possible? Thanks

**EDIT:** my script

```
set.seed(1)
mymatrix <- matrix(rnorm(25, mean=0.7, sd=0.2), ncol=5) # random matrix mean 0.7
mymatrix[lower.tri(mymatrix)] = t(mymatrix)[lower.tri(mymatrix)] # make it symmetric
mymatrix[mymatrix>1]<-0.7 # make numbers between 0 and 1
mymatrix[mymatrix<0]<-0.7
library(bindata)
res=rmvbin(1000, margprob=diag(mymatrix), bincorr = mymatrix)
#### Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
#### Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a toy example and provide the exact text of the "error telling me that the random correlation matrix I give is not right."

Comment: @lmo Thanks, see the edit..

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix(mymatrix from the snippet) is not positive definite and it cannot be a valid covariance matrix, let alone being a valid correlation matrix as its diagonal entries are not 1's. Try to build a random covariance matrix by multiplying a random matrix with its transpose so that it is a positive-definite at least. To build a correlation matrix, you need to rescale the covariance matrix accordingly. An example,

```
rmat <- matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
cov_mat <- rmat%*%t(rmat)
corr_mat <- cov_mat/sqrt(diag(cov_mat)%*%t(diag(cov_mat)))
```

As for the original problem of generating multivariate Bernoulli vectors with specified correlation structure, refer to the following [article](http://www.science.oregonstate.edu/~madsenl/files/MadsenBirkes2013.pdf). Basically, you need to use Gaussian copula. For Bernoulli case, it's relatively simple algebra for each pair of variables. I guess the packages you mentioned above do that for you.

[EDIT] For Bernoulli vectors, not all correlation matrices are admissible. Think of simple three variable case, where the marginal probabilities are 0.5 each. Doing simple algebra, you get the correlation of (X_i,X_j) to be 4E[X_i*X_j]-1. They are in range of [-1,1] for each pair. Suppose that you want the correlation of (X_i,X_j) to be -0.5 for all i,j not equal. This requires E[X_i*X_j] = 1/8 for all i,j not equal. If you try to draw a Venn diagram of three subset of a sample space where each subset covers half of the sample space and each pair has overlap of only 1/8 of the sample space, you can easily see that this is logically impossible.

So, the bottom line is that you need to provide logically feasible binary correlation matrix to the function. It cannot be any valid correlation matrix. If you don't care about specific correlation coefficients, just use Gaussian copula with any valid correlation matrix. For your package of interest, you can do it by

```
rmvbin(1000,margprob=rep(0.5,5),sigma=corr_mat)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i understand your first paragraph but the article you mention is really too complicated for my math knowledge.... i tried to rerun my code with your modif but is says: "Warning: Resulting covariance matrix is not positive definite".All values returned are NA.

Comment: see the EDIT above.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive input. I understand now why it's difficult to come up with a valid matrix. However, with your code I do get some random data output without errors, though I'm still struggling on how to control the distribution of the correlations in the corr_mat.